# Erlang: Pass a tcp socket as stdin to a UNIX process

Tags: sockets, erlang, file-descriptor

I need to run a UNIX process from Erlang, and set a TCP socket as stdin.  Is that possible?

Right now I have a TCP socket I've gotten from [Ranch](http://ninenines.eu/docs/en/ranch/HEAD/index.html), and I can get its file descriptor, but I'm not sure how to set that as stdin for the UNIX process I'm creating. Looking through the `open_port` [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#open_port-2) didn't provide me any clues on how to do that.

The reason I need to do this is the process I'm invoking is hard coded to expect its standard in to be a socket, and it's crashing if it isn't. This means I can't just open it with `open_port` and proxy the TCP stream to it.

I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Have you considered creating a FIFO? Invoke mkfifo with os:cmd, open the new file to write with file:open, use os:cmd to invoke the external process? Not remotely elegant, but should do the trick.

Comment: Will the end process see the FIFO as a TCP port? Right now it's asserting stdin is an IPV4 or IPV6 socket. Not what I would have done, but I don't have expertise in that application...

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems: being able to i/o calls to the socket, and making it the processes `standard_io` for i/o:

- Each process has a *group leader* which is a process to which all i/o requests which don't have a specific i/o device in the call are sent. This can be set using the BIF `erlang:group_leader/2` to set a process's group leader. The group leader is inherited when a process is spawned which is why all processes spawned from the shell send their output the same as the shell, even if it is spawned on another node.
- The next problem is fixing it so you can do Erlang i/o requests, for example `io:format` to/from your TCP socket. All i/o in Erlang must go through an i/o server which implements the [Erlang i/o protocol](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/io_protocol.html). It is the i/o server which handles i/o requests from Erlang code and translates them into sending/receiving data from the external. I have implemented [TCP i/o server](https://github.com/rvirding/tcp_io_server) which is on GitHub. There is no documentation as such but some examples at the bottom, for example one which opens a listen socket and for each new connection starts a shell which handles i/o through that socket. It is very short code actually.

So that is basically what you need to do to get i/o between a process/group of processes and a TCP port.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think there's some terminology confusion between OS and Erlang processes in my question.  I tried to make it clearer in my edit.